# How to use wrapper type argument in Swift extension

Tags: swift, generics

I want to introduce some connections between types in my type extension. Consider following example.

```
struct Wrapper<T> {
    var target: T?
}

struct Container<T> {
    var wrapper: T?
}

extension Container where T == Wrapper<Any> {

    func unwrap() -> Any {
        return wrapper!.target!
    }


}
```

This compiles, but if I want to use it like this.

```
var wrapper = Wrapper<String>()
wrapper.target = "foo"
var container = Container<Wrapper<String>>()
container.wrapper = wrapper
let string: String  = container.unwrap()
```

Above code ends with compilation error

```
Container<Wrapper<String>>' is not convertible to 'Container<Wrapper<Any>>
```

So to be clear. Is there a way to indicate that type argument from extension constraint is a return type of new method. So it could be used somelike

```
extension Container where T == Wrapper<NEWTYPEARGUMENT> {

    func unwrap() -> NEWTYPEARGUMENT {
        return wrapper!.target!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, Swift doesn't support introducing generic type constraints in extensions using where clauses. However, you can achieve what you are trying to do by introducing the type constraint directly to the generic function using a where clause.

```
extension Container {
    func unwrap<U>() -> U where T == Wrapper<U> {
        return wrapper!.target!
    }
}

var wrapper = Wrapper<String>()
wrapper.target = "foo"
var container = Container<Wrapper<String>>()
container.wrapper = wrapper
let string: String  = container.unwrap() //"foo"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for